# Databricks and Pylint Integration

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, pylint, pylintrc

Is there any way to integrate Databricks and pylint for liniting pyspark/python code? If not, are there any alternatives for the same ?

Comment: by Databricks are you referring to the code in the notebooks? or what?

Comment: the alternative I can think of is to use your fav IDE and push your Pyspark code to Databricks using their DBX utility. https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/dbx.html

Comment: @AlexOtt yes Alex, I am referring to the notebooks in databricks.

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran Yes, Ganesh, I have already look into to, but that won't work for me.